Access to local Ubuntu server (SSH, Samba, etc.) is blocked after installing Docker containers or the deb version of Plex Media Server
I am a beginner. I've only set up Ubuntu servers in my home for fun a total of 3 times. This is a home lab setup intended for Samba file sharing, Plex media server, and eventually Nextcloud.
Hardware setup:
I am running the latest LTS version of Ubuntu 24.04.1 server on a mini PC with an Intel N95 x4 processor, 8GB RAM, 4TB M.2 NVME SSD, and it's hard-wired to my ASUS-RT-AX86U router which runs my local network. There is an unmanaged Netgear switch between the mini-PC and the router. I have set up the mini-PC server to have a static local IP in the router settings.
My PC, which I was using to SSH into the server, is a desktop machine running Fedora 36, also connect by wire, directly to the router.
The problem:
I setup SSH and Samba file sharing with no issue, and was able to control both from my Fedora PC. These work perfectly until I try to install a service/app on the server, such as Plex. Whether I install it via Docker or straight onto the server using a deb package, as soon as Plex is up an running, I lose the ability to connect to the server via SSH or Samba from my Fedora PC.
If I uninstall Plex, the issue remains and I have to wait 24-48 hrs. After that, I can connect to SSH and Samba again. If I try to install Plex another way, the same issue occurs. I cannot find any references to this issue or why I would need to wait a certain number of hours for everything to work again after installing an app like Plex.
My suspicions were that the app/service was advertising itself on the local network and somehow overpowering to such a degree that I cannot connect to server machine's IP using a different port. But again, I cannot find reference to this issue.
The error I get from the terminal when trying to SSH is:
ssh: connect to host 192.168.50.248 port 22: No route to host

The error I get when trying to access the Samba file share from my PC's file manager is:
Unhandled error message: Failed to mount Windows share: No route to host

Troubleshooting I have tried:

I tried configuring port settings in ufw and even disabling ufw entirely to test if this was the cause.
I have tried restarting the ssh and sshd services, Samba, ufw, and rebooted both machines multiple times.
When I gave up on the Docker version of Plex, I uninstalled Docker to remove that variable. I then installed Plex directly using the deb package, but that has not changed the problem. (Side note: Plex is finally working at least using this method! I was having errors with the Docker versions.)


UPDATE: I waited a few more hours and the SSH and Samba began working again. However, I lost access to SSH again after loading the Plex web portal on my Fedora PC. The web portal then went down. Samba was still working though.
I can still access the web portal on the server machine with no crashes. The crash only seems to occur when I try to access it from a different PC. (I have the Ubuntu server mini-PC connected to a monitor with GNOME desktop environment, which is why I can test the web portal there.)

UPDATE: Samba is now down as well, shortly after my previous comment above. I will wait longer to see if it resets again after 24 hours.
